# UI API called on background thread error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've a code that checks if the `applicationState` of the app. I've also ensure thread safety to the call of `applicationState`. However, I still get the error saying, `Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]`. What could be the possible reason

```
+(BOOL)isExecutingInBackground {
    __block BOOL retVal = NO;
    if([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        retVal = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground;
    }
    else {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            retVal = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground;
        });
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: try with removing dispatch_sync.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: add just  retVal = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground; instead of dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            retVal = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground;
        });

Comment: That is definite error - because,`applicationState` should always be taken in main thread

Comment: Why don't you call `isExecutingInBackground` Method itself in main thread and remove all if-else ? may be helpful

Comment: Its called from many different places. Additionally (as per OOPS), the caller of this method should not be bothered about mainThread and all, but this  abstraction should be provided by the method.

Comment: then you need to change your logic, Create a boolean in app delegate, Update its state in UIAplication delegate "applicationDidEnterBackground" and in "applicationWillEnterForeground" and use this boolean value